# Using .Net Core 2.2 classes in 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need a specific functionality that was recently added into .Net Core 2.2 (new enhancements to GzipStream class in System.IO.Compression), however I'm using AWS Lambda and the latest version supported there is 2.1

Is there a way to extract the required DLL from 2.2 package and use it with 2.1 solution? I found the DLL and referenced it in my project, but it didn't seem to work (seems like it's simply ignored). Am i missing a step?

Comment: theoretically, you should be able to deploy as a self-contained application, regardless of the framework available on AWS at the moment. Another option would be a container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not possible because a .net DLL has written into it the version of .NET. So as the version is later than your project, the compiler will ignore it.

Even if it were possible, there would be no guarantee that it would not refer to other .net core 2.2 methods, which would make you look for more DLLs in that version.

maybe you should be change the project version to 2.2